# Jupyter notebook does not launch on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've installed jupyter in Windows with the command `pip install jupyter` When I type `jupyter-notebook` I'm getting the following error

```
Start : Este comando no se puede ejecutar debido al error: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Start "file:///home/<user>/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-254- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

How can I debug this? I've tried to run this with an Ubuntu application (on Windows) and with wsl2 without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, but I know from answering [here about starting pip installed JupyterLab](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/error-while-running-jupyter-lab-or-jupyter-lab-on-windows-machine/10341/2?u=fomightez) the commands sometimes don't match what is stated in places. Did you try `jupyter notebook` without the dash? Plus what is discussed in that thread may give you some other ideas such as making sure things are on your PATH.